# Herstein's proof of transcendence of $e$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, inequality, transcendental-numbers

This question concerns Herstein's proof (in *Topics in Algebra*) that $e$ is transcendental. If you have the book, it's Theorem 5.2.1, page 218, or there's a transcription here: [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~palmieri/Courses/2005/Math403/transcendental.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Epalmieri/Courses/2005/Math403/transcendental.pdf).

In the final step, he goes from $$\epsilon_i = \frac{-ie^{i\left(1-\theta_i\right)}\left(i\theta_i\right)^{p-1}\left(1-i\theta_i\right)^p \dotsm \left(n-i\theta_i\right)^p}{(p-1)!}$$ to $$\lvert\epsilon_i\rvert \leq \frac{e^n n^p \left(n!\right)^p}{(p-1)!}$$
I can see where most of this estimate comes from, but am having difficulty with the $\left(n!\right)^p$ part. This seems to assume that $$\left\lvert\left(1-i\theta_i\right) \dotsm \left(n-i\theta_i\right)\right\rvert \leq n! \qquad (*)$$ but some of the terms inside the absolute value will be negative (the $\theta_i$ are between 0 and 1, but $i$ can range from $1$ to $n$), so we can't just multiply the inequalities $1-i\theta_i < 1$, $2-i\theta_i < 2$, etc. So can anyone clarify how the inequality $(*)$ arises? Thanks very much in advance for assistance.

Comment: Good observation, and $(*)$ is definitely not true in general—imagine that $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{n/2}=1$ while $\theta_{n/2+1},\dots,\theta_n=0$ and $i=n$, for example. (One can change $\theta_n$ specifically to $1$ to keep $i\theta_i$ large and still break $(*)$.)

Comment: There is something confusing about this product, does it have $i$ factors or $n$ factors?

Comment: I corrected it; it's $n$ factors.

Comment: For future reference: Using the index $i$ here is highly confusing, because we might expect to have $e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, quite. Herstein does it I suppose because he's an algebraist.

Comment: I think you'll find lots of $i=\sqrt{-1}$'s in Herstein's book :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Herstein's book it reads $(1-i\theta_i) \cdots (n-i \theta_i)$, not $(1-i\theta_1) \cdots (n-i \theta_i)$. I think this is easily seen to be bounded by $n!$.

In fact, let $k$ be the smallest integer with $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $k - i \theta_i > 0$. Then $(n-i \theta_i) \cdots (k - i \theta_i) \leq (n-k+1)!$. For the remaining factors we have $\left| (1-i\theta_i) \cdots (k-1 - i\theta_i)\right| \leq (k-1)!$, where we say the empty product equals $1$. The total product therefore is bounded by $(n-k+1)!(k-1)!$ which equals $n!/\binom{n}{k-1}\leq n!$.

Comment: How do we know the absolute value is bounded by $(k-1)!$? As the terms inside are still negative

Comment: We're dealing with absolute values, and the absolute value of the product is the same as the product of the absolute values. So the minus signs really do not matter at all.

Comment: But we don't know that e.g. $\left\lvert 1-i\theta_i\right\rvert < 1$: indeed, if e.g. $i = n$ and $\theta_i$ is close to $1$ then it won't be.

Comment: @Prasiortle Yes, but that's why I introduced the variable $k$: we *do* know that $\left|k-1-i \theta_i \right| < 1$, $\left|k-2-i \theta_i \right| < 2$, etc. You have to split the product up into the positive part and the negative part, and if you estimate them separately, you get the desired result.

Comment: $\left\lvert k - 1 - i\theta_i\right\rvert = 1 + i\theta_i - k$, so to say it's less than $1$, we would need $i\theta_i < k$, which again it may not be if e.g. $i=n$ and $\theta_i$ is close to $1$. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Prasiortle But look at how I defined $k$. It is defined by the very property that $k > i \theta_i$ and $k-1 \leq i \theta_i$. If it's still not clear, just look at it this way: we have a product of $n$ factors, with each next factor being just $1$ less than the previous one. So at some point the factors become negative, and I have defined $k$ in such a way as to separate the positive factors from the negative ones.

Comment: Ah, that solves it - I got the idea of splitting up the positive and negative terms but didn't see that this would also give the required $i\theta_i > k$ bound. Thanks for sticking with it!